# Equivalent metrics have the same compact set.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness, solution-verification

**Statement:**

> Let $(X,d_1)$ and $(X,d_2)$ be two equivalent metrics. Such that The ball $B_{d_1}(x,r_1)\subseteq B_{d_2}(x,r)$. Similarly, $B_{d_2}(x,r_2)\subseteq B_{d_1}(x,r)$. Show that they have the same compact subset

**Approach:**

In order for these two to have the same compact subset. We need a $G$ which is closed and bounded wrt to $d_1$ this implies that it $G$  is also closed and bounded wrt to $d_2$. In order for $G$ to be closed wrt to $d_1$ $G^c$ has to be open in $X$, every point of $X\cap G^c$ is an interior point of $X\cap G^c$ in $X$. If we let $G^c$ be open in $X$, then for every $x\in G^c$ we can find a radii $r>0$ such that $y\in G^c$ whenver $y\in X$ and $d(x,y)<r$. Let $B_d(x,r)$ be the open ball in $X$, then

$$G^c=\bigcup_{x\in G^c}B_{d_1}(x,r_1)$$

is open in $X$ and $G=X\cap G^c$. Since $d_1$ and $d_2$ are equivalent , then by our definitoon

$$G^c\subseteq\bigcup_{x\in G^c}B_{d_1}(x,r_1)\subseteq\bigcup_{x\in G^c}B_{d_2}(x,r_2)=G^c$$

Hence, $G^c$ is open in both metrics. For these to both be bounded, $G$ has to be bounded in $X$ wrt to $d_1$ $\Longrightarrow$ $G$ is also bounded wrt $d_2$. Let $M>0$, since $d_1(x,y)\geq 0$, implying that $d_1(x,y) + 1 >0$ and $d_1(x,y) < d_2(x,y)+1$.

**Questions:**

- Is this a correct approach to show that they have the same compact subset?
- Is my proof that they have the same closed set valid?
- I don't know how to continue my proof for both of them being bounded, how would I continue?

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is not correct since, in general, being compact is *not* equivalent to being closed and bounded.

Asserting that $K$ is compact with respect to $d_1$ means that, given a family $\{A_\lambda\mid\lambda\in\Lambda\}$ of open subsets of $(X,d_1)$ such that $K\subset\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}A_\lambda$, there is a finite set $F\subset\Lambda$ such that $K\subset\bigcup_{\lambda\in F}A_\lambda$. But the open sets of $(X,d_1)$ and the open sets of $(X,d_2)$ are the *same* sets. So, if this occurs in $(X,d_1)$, then it also occurs in $(X,d_2)$ (and vice versa).

Comment: But shouldn't I treat this kind of question as an $K$ compact to $d_1$ iff $K$ compact to $d_2$

Comment: Yes. And that's why I treated it like that.

Comment: I think I get it, I'll update the proof in a bit.

Comment: Do you mean that you shall edit your question in a way such that my answer will no longer be an answer?

Comment: I can post my update on the proof here, in the comment section. But I was orignally thinking to add an "Update" under the questions, but posting it here should be the same I guess.

Comment: Let $K$ be a compact subset of $X$ wrt $d_1$. Since it is compact wrt $d_1$ $\exists (V_\alpha)_{\alpha\in I}$ which is a collection of open sets in $X$ wrt $d_1$. Hence, $K\subseteq \bigcup_{\alpha\in I} V_\alpha$, but since this is true. There also exists a finite subset $F$ of $I$ s.t $K\subseteq \bigcup_{\alpha \in F} V_\alpha$. Let $y\in K$. Then $y$ must lie in atleast one of the sets $V_\alpha$. Since each $V_\alpha$ is open then $\exists r_1$ s.t $B_{d_1}(x,r_1) \subseteq V_\alpha$. Is this a correct approach now?

Comment: No, this is not correct. For **every** subset $S$ of $X$ (compact or not) there is a collection of open subsets of $(X,d_1)$ such that $S$ is a subset of their union. Is there something wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the fact that a subset $K$ of a metric space $(X,d)$ is compact iff any sequence $(x_n) \subset K$ has a converging subsequence.